# Replace de textos no word importando dados do Excel

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Bom dia pessoal, estou iniciando na área de programação e estou tentando realizar um automatismo de preenchimento de um documento word importando dados de células do Excel. Aonde no word aonde será substituído terá o número da célula do Excel.

Mas o replace só está ocorrendo se a célula ter letra, e terei algumas células somente com números. Teria outra variável que fizesse o reconhecimento tanto de letras quanto de número? Se sim, teria outro impacto em mais partes do código que estou utilizando?

Biblioteca utilizada: docx

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from docx import Document
from docx import *

# Carregando uma planilha já existente
bd = load_workbook('excel_teste.xlsx')

# Carrega documento Word
doc = Document('teste.docx')

# Pegando uma aba específica (exemplo: aba1)
aba_1 = bd['P2']

# Percorrendo e lendo a primeira coluna
for x in range(30):
    celula = 'B' + str(x + 3)
    texto = aba_1[celula].value

    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        if celula in p.text:
            inline = p.runs
            # Loop added to work with runs (strings with same style)
            for i in range(len(inline)):
                    if celula in inline[i].text:
                        text = inline[i].text.replace(celula, texto)
                        inline[i].text = text
    
    for table in doc.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for p in cell.paragraphs:
                    if celula in p.text:
                        inline = p.runs
                        for i in range(len(inline)):
                                if celula in inline[i].text:
                                    text = inline[i].text.replace(celula, texto)
                                    inline[i].text = text
# save the modified document
doc.save('updated.docx')
```

Answer (score 0):

O excel trata diferente celular com valores numericos dos caracteres, use a função `IsNull` ou `IsEmpty`
Ex

```
If Not IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) Then
      ...
   End If
```

ou

```
If Not IsNull(Range("A1").Value) Then
      ...
   End If
```

Comment: Poderia me indicar aonde adicionar esse trecho de codigo?